# Discord Buttons Interaction Failed

Tags: python, button, discord, interaction

so my question is simply how can i get rid of this annoying "Interaction failed" thingy? Everything works well, and the buttons also do work. Once the button finished loading, and the action got performed, it simply says "Interaction failed" for no reason. Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def update(self, ctx, *, args):
    if ctx.author.id == 703671503954378782:
        now = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%D %H:%M')
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(906589215645646918)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Server/Bot update", description=f"{args}", color=0x71368a)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author}", icon_url=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{now}", icon_url=f"{ctx.guild.icon_url}")
        tembed = discord.Embed(title="Confirmation",
                                   description=f"Do you want me to send this announcement?\n**Announcement**:\n{args}",
                                   color=discord.Colour.random())
        await ctx.reply(embed=tembed, components=[
                [Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Send"), Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Cancel")]])
        res = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click")
        if res.component.label == "Send":
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.reply("Update has been sent!")
        if res.component.label == "Cancel":
            await ctx.reply("Interaction cancelled.")
        else:
            await ctx.reply("You're not permitted to use this command!")
```

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Assuming you are using the `discord-components` library, this can be accomplished by responding to the interaction with type 6 ([DEFERRED_UPDATE_MESSAGE](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#interaction-response-object-interaction-callback-type)). [More info here](https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/guide/frequently-asked-questions#how-do-i-ignore-the-interaction).

### Code

```py
await res.respond(type=6)
```